# What sign in the sky did the Magi see, a star or a group of planets?

Tags: magi, astronomy

We hear in Matthew 2:1-2 the Magi saying that they came in search of the newborn king of the Jews, whose star they had seen in the east.

Matthew 2:1, 2 KJV

> <sup>**1**</sup> Now when Jesus was born in Bethlehem of Judaea in the days of Herod the king, behold, there came wise men from the east to Jerusalem, <sup>**2**</sup> Saying, Where is he that is born King of the Jews? for we have seen his star in the east, and are come to worship him.

Astronomers suggest that it was not a star, but a rare conjunction of the planets that the Magi had seen. Every 805 years, in a rare phenomenon, planets Jupiter and Saturn take position of just one degree apart. German astronomer Johannes Kepler (1571-1630)reported such a union to have taken place during Christmas time in 1603 AD. As such, the phenomenon took place in 7 BC.  The 'moving' of the sign as mentioned in the Gospel is also in tune with the theory that it was a planet rather than a star.

What sign in the sky did the Magi see, a star or a group of planets?

Comment: Bob Moler explains, and animates, the astronomical event in 7 BC when over 6 months, three times Jupiter passed Saturn and the conjunction became static in Pisces. In early 6 BC Mars conjoined too, and at some point the moon as well. Seems reasonable then that perhaps the Magi might have read into the event enough significance to journey. It is thought that Pisces was associated with the Hebrews, Jupiter with the Messiah or world ruler, and Saturn with the peoples. Moler explains https://tinyurl.com/34v4c3y9 - Amazing coincidence otherwise!

Answer (score 3):

The "star" that the Magi saw, whatever it was, was not a conjunction of planets, nor an actual star, nor a comet, for the following reasons:

1. Stars, planetary conjunctions, and comets appear to move in the sky as the earth rotates.  However, this "star" guided the Magi from the east (Matthew 2:1) to Jerusalem and then **south** to Bethlehem, and then remained stationary:

   Matthew 2:9

   > After they had heard the king, they went on their way, and the star they had seen in the east went ahead of them until it **stood over the place where the Child** was.
2. The learned Magi almost certainly had access to advanced astronomical methods such as those used by the ancient Greek mathematicians who could predict eclipses and conjunctions well in advance.  The Magi would have been astute enough to have ignored a natural phenomenon - they were looking for the star prophesied by Balaam:

   Numbers 24:17

   > I see him, but not now; I behold him, but not near. A star will come forth from Jacob, and a scepter will arise from Israel. He will crush the skulls of Moab and strike down all the sons of Sheth.
3. A natural astronomical "star"/comet/conjunction rises in the east and sets in the west - however the Magi's star consistently guided them toward Jerusalem.  According to Matthew 2:1, the Magi came from the east (most likely the Parthian kingdom of old Persia as suggested by the word "Magi" - a Persian word).  Thus, the Magi would have initially traveled northwest and then south to Jerusalem.  No natural heavenly body moves thus over a six or eight-week period.
4. A planetary conjunction such as suggested by the OP only lasts a few days to a week - not long enough to guide the Magi.
5. All natural heavenly bodies are too far distant to be able to be associated with a single location.  However, the Magi's star is described as "standing over the place where the Child was".  That is, the Magi were led to the very house/stable where Jesus was.

**Conclusion**

We are not told exactly what the miraculous guiding star was.  All that can be said is that it was miraculous and not a natural phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks, Dottard. Please do clear a doubt: the Magi referred to the phenomenon as HIS Star. That would imply that they had followed some predictions and/or calculations of celestial events. Was it not possible that the Jews had long ago been given a hint that they eventually forgot after sharing with the Persians ?

Comment: Point 5 is the strongest argument. The apparent motion of a star moving from above Jerusalem to above Bethlehem is about ⅛ of the width of the Moon, a distance that no human, even a Magi, could notice, much less use for navigation.  And even if they could, the fixed stars move that much about every 15 seconds, making a useful observation even more fantastic. Whatever it was they saw, it had to be very close to the ground.

Comment: @RayButterworth - excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

In the Greek, the word for 'sign' is *semeion,* from which we get the English word 'semaphore'. Different flags representing different letters of the alphabet are waved and tracked by the observing party some distance away, to understand the word that must be understood.

In the book of the Revelation, there are three great heavenly signs, the first drawing attention to the woman clothed with the sun, the moon under her feet, a crown of 12 stars on her head. She is giving birth. Christians understand this to refer to the entrance of the Word of God into this world. After all, the great red dragon awaiting this birth wants to destroy the male child instantly. And what did Herod the Great do but get all baby boys in the locality murdered by his soldiers when God ensured the Magi did not return to him with the Christ-child's location?

That is why one small group claims that what the Magi saw, that led them to Jerusalem, was a star-sign sent by Satan. But what if it was of God, part of fulfilling the prophecy of Jeremiah 31:15? And what if we take into account the fact that the word 'planet' is a comparatively recent 'invention', based on modern telescopes that have shown the difference between stars and planets? In the Bible, all heavenly bodies apart from the sun and the moon are called 'stars'. The word 'planets' had not been invented.

This means that whatever it was that the Magi saw, certainly led them to travel a huge distance over very many months, all prepared to find a new king in Israel. This is where a planetary conjunction could fit the bill. The first aspect of the series of three would have alerted them to the next two; they would have astronomical data going back centuries to calculate when to expect the next weird (apparent) moving backwards of two stars (in their books - planets in ours) which would have caused an unusual brightness for a while; repeated at the third aspect. The second aspect led them to Jerusalem where they visited Herod who might have thought them spies had they not paid him a courtesy call. There they had confirmation of what they believed they should find - a new king. That must have choked king Herod, who (nevertheless) kept up pleasant appearances in order to get his murderous hands on any such new king. The third conjunction then duly appeared, looking as if it was right over a particular stable in Bethlehem.

This means, then, that the Bible account had no need to anticipate 20th Century A.D.  language. The word 'stars' sufficed for the Magi, as it does for us. The heavenly sign is not what matters, for a sign merely points to something - the reality that needs to be seen. Whatever the Magi saw was leading them towards, pointing them to, the new-born babe of Bethlehem. That is what Christians must never tire of repeating to a visual-obsessed world, taken up with what their eyes see, when it is spiritual signs pointing to spiritual realities that the Bible deals with. **The Magi understood the star-sign that led them to Mary and the Christ-child.** Do we understand the word-signs in the Bible that point us to the Word of God made flesh?

Answer (score 1):

We know that Jesus was born in a manger in a stable in Bethlehem.  In those years, travelers used the stars for navigation.  All they did was follow the unusually bright star till they got to Bethlem, this however was some days after Jesus had been born.

Matthew 2:11

> And when they were come into the house, they saw the young child with Mary his mother, and fell down, and worshipped him: and when they had opened their treasures, they presented unto him gifts; gold, and frankincense, and myrrh.

As you can see from the scripture above "...they were come into the house ..." So it is a misconception that the three wise men (magi) arrived at the manger in a stable the night Jesus was born.